# Comparison between char and char not working

Tags: c

I have made a (very bad) attempt at a crackme.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char passphrase[20];
    printf("Welcome to first_level.\n");
    printf("Hello. What's your passphrase?\n");

    fgets(passphrase,20,stdin);

    passphrase[strcspn(passphrase, "\n")] = 0;

    if(strlen(passphrase) != 10){
        // you lost
    } else
    {
        int counter = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            char index = i;
            char currentChar = passphrase[i];
            //printf(passphrase[i]);
            printf("---\nindex: %d\nchar: %c\n",index, currentChar);
            if(index == currentChar){
                //printf("ass\n");
                counter++;
            }
        }
        if(counter == 10)
        {
            printf("Congrats!\n");
            return 0;
        }

        printf("counter %d\n", counter);
    }

    printf("You lost!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Now theoretically, the char comparison should work. Unfortunately, I believe that the characters are converted to int, and then compared.

With the magical printf before the comparison I noticed that if I printed the number (%d), the char would be >48, while when printing the character (%c -- like the code provided), the character number is printed correctly.

I am wondering how could I do this? I tried `strcmp` already but obviously it expects a string and not a char.

Comment: So why isn't this working then?

Comment: `if(index == currentChar)` ==> `if (index == currentChar - '0')`

Comment: Could you explain why?

Comment: The code boils down to `if(i == passphrase[i])` where `i` is in the range 0 to 9. Can you see why it won't be equal?

Comment: Not really. The intended password is "0123456789"

Comment: Well the first character has the value (if ASCII) of `48` not `0`. As @pmg wrote, subracting `'0'` from the characters puts them in the range 0 to 9.

Comment: So do I need to add 48 to the index before comparing? Like so: `if(passphrase[i] == i +48)` ? Also, I convert the `i` to a char, and the char of `i = 0` should hold the value 48, if I understand correctly, but it doesnt?

Comment: Don't hard code the `48` use `'0'`. It is clearer and portable.

Comment: Got it. Could you answer my second question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C Standard mandates that the characters `'0'`, `'1'`, ..., and `'9'` be sequential and consecutive. So we know the value of `'1'` is 1 greater than the value of `'0'` (and similarly for the other digits).

Taking the above into consideration, we know that

```
'0' - '0' == 0;
'1' - '0' == 1;
....
'9' - '0' == 9;
```

Note that all of the above **must** work as I described, whether running on an ASCII based computer, or EBCDIC, or Klingon, or whatever.

So, to compare digits in character form (`'0'`, ..., `'9'`) with integer values (`0`, ..., `9`) simply subtract `'0'` from the char.

```
if (index == currentChar - '0') /* ... */;
```